# If I step up 9V to 12V with a boost converter, what happens when the input goes to 12V?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, dc-dc-converter, boost

I want to use either a 9 V or 12 V power supply. If the input is 9 V, I want to step it up to 12 V with a boost converter. But if the input is 12 V will the output still be 12 V or will it be boosted to 15 V or so.

The boost converter is the [XL6009](http://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/XL6009/XL6009-DC-DC-Converter-Datasheet.pdf).

Comment: What circuit are you using with the Xl6009 chip? And can components be changed or is it all fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output voltage is set by the feedback pin voltage, which in turn is set by a resistive divider. The regulator aims to ensure that the feedback pin stays at its comparative reference voltage (1.25V in this case) by adjusting the output voltage. Given that the reference is set by fixed resistors, then it is in principal entirely independent of the input voltage. That means if you set the regulator to 12V out, you will get 12V out regardless of whether the input voltage is 5V, 9V, 10V, etc.

However in practice things aren't so simple. The DC/DC converter will have input vs output voltage requirements that must be met. Those conditions will depend on the topology of your circuit (hence @Jodes question I presume).

If you wire up the XL6009 as a boost converter, the input voltage must be less than the output voltage for correct regulation. Conversely if you wire it up as a buck converter, the input voltage must be higher than the output voltage.

In order to work with both a 12V and a 9V input, you will need to use the buck-boost topology. This should allow the regulator to both step up the voltage if the input is lower than the required output voltage, or step it down if the input is higher (or equal).

Answer (score 1):

You won't get \$ V_o = 12V \$ with \$ V_i = 12V \$.

The control loop of the XL6009 will try to drive the internal switching element in the XL6009 into a duty cycle close to 0% (in continuous mode) when trying to force \$ V_o = V_i \$ at any \$ V_i \$ close to \$ 12V \$.

However the rising and falling times of the switching element will limit the minimum and maximum duty cycle considering the rather high \$ f_{osc} = 400kHz\$. The datasheet states \$ D_{max} = 90\% \$, so we can probably assume that \$ D_{min} = 10\% \$.

Thus, in continuous mode \$ V_{i,MAX} = (1-D_{min})V_o = 0.9 \cdot 12V = 10.8V\$. What will happen above \$ V_i = 10.8V \$? Probably, the control loop will stop trying to force \$ V_o = V_i \$ and will start to follow the input according to this relationship:

$$
V_o \approx \frac {V_i} {(1-D_{min})} \approx 1.11 \cdot V_i
$$

or just leave the internal switch fully open (i.e. \$ D = 0\% \$) and leave the output follow the input minus the diode drop.

Conclusion: use a buck-boost topology instead.